# Escape filter parameter in custom connector's action

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-apps-custom-connector

What is the proper way to specify an action's url containing a filter when defining it for a custom connector? I'd like to use this:

> ```
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{gid}/members?$filter=id eq '{uid}'
> ```

It correctly recognizes `{gid}`, but it recognizes `$filter` as a parameter and `{uid}` not at all. Do I need to escape the `$filter` somehow or do something entirely different?